# How to create a heatmap using 3 variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap using the below variables:
I have a x-value which represents distance in the x-direction (in meters).
I have a z-value which represents depth (in meters).
I have a saturation value (in percentage).

What I am trying to do is to create a heatmap that covers the aforementioned things and shows that at saturations between 0-10%, it is dark blue, 10-20% lighter blue than the previous one, ... all the way to 90-100% saturation, it is the lightest blue possible.

Appreciate the help.

I am completely new and I want to get my feet wet with this example.

Comment: You may be new, but questions need to be aged somewhat. Write some code.  Try it.  If it works, great, carry on.  If not, then post the code with a description of what happened and what you expected to happen, differently.

Comment: You will find that people here are happy to help anyone whose feet are wet and who fears they may be drowning.  You have to get your feet wet yourself: read a book, take a course, look at someone else's code.

Comment: You may want to look into seaborn's [heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).  The examples first use pandas' `pivot` to create a "wide form" dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out plotting the heatmap.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('Example.xlsx')

k = df.pivot('Z(m)','X(m)','SatGas')
plt.title('Gas Saturation at year 1 of injection')
#heat_map = sns.heatmap(k, cmap="jet")

ax = sns.heatmap(tough_stuff, cmap="jet")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(tough_stuff, cmap="jet", ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(1, 25)
plt.show()
```

However, I am unable to do the following:

- I want my x-axis to increase by 50 in the x-axis.
- I want my y-axis to be reversed and increase by 5.